# Multipage text report template with Jasper (or Birt)

Tags: jasper-reports, birt

In iReport I can create single page template easy, but when have long static text with some inline fields, can't make that multipage template.

I tried create text field in raport, with very long static text and some variables inline:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="82249f31-5b1d-4bff-951d-ad6da7f743c3">
    <field name="field1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="d966bf72-21f3-4393-b69b-1e4f36b31255" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="79" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="24"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["some text some some: " +  $F{field1} + "very long textvery long text very long text verymultipage ...... "]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

Effect: only one page document.
So How I can create multipage template?

Would like template like this:

[image]

Comment: When set isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" can create multipage, but can't insert tables between text blocks.

Is any other java reporting framework can this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried BIRT yet? The text field uses the BIRT master page size that you set. If there is more content than can fit into the master page size, additional pages are created and your content flows into the other pages.

Comment: Yes, I checked BIRT and many other frameworks, but not found good solution for my. Probably best for this was aspose word, but commercial.